# How can I stop a recursion from the base condition?

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking

I am facing following problem with recursion. It is simple backtracking to print all the permutation, but I want to stop it from the base condition. For example, 4 character string will show 4!=24 strings. But I want to show first 20 strings only.
k is used for the purpose, k=20,for the example. Suppose, str="ABCD". I want to stop recursion after exactly 20 operations. How can I do this? I have tried to solve it in this way.

```
void permutation(string str,int l,int r,int k)
{
    k--;
    if(l==r||k==0) {
        cout<<str<<endl;
        return;
    }
    else{
    for(int i=l;i<r;i++)
    {
        swap(str[l],str[i]);
        permutation(str,l+1,r,k);
        swap(str[l],str[i]);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't print upto 20 permutations. It shows all the 24.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the unfortunately named `k` as a counter like that, it will count recursion levels, not results. If you want to count results, you need to store the counter outside of your function, either as a static or as a reference you pass to your function, and increment it every time you output a result.

Comment: Ditto on refactoring in some more descriptive names. Good names help others to understand your code better, which makes it easier for others to work with you. Disk space isn't costly anymore and long variables names are easy to type with IDE autocomplete tools, so there's generally no remaining reason to use extremely condensed variable names.

Comment: Then, shall I call a global variable count=0 and increase it by one after each permutation?

Comment: I'd suggest `resultCount`, but yeah you have the right idea!

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions to count the number of times results are printed:
1- Defining `k` as a global variable outside the function.
2- Defining `k` as a static variable: `static int k = 0;`.

Note that in both these solutions, `k` should be eliminated from the parameter list of the function.

I would also suggest choosing meaningful names for your variables. This way, it will be easier to understand and follow the code both for you and someone else who is going to help.